# How can i insert data to the particular newly created column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a single new column in the existing table. How can i insert data to that particular newly created column in postgres?

Comment: try to update the newly created column by any one of existing columns.

Comment: `UPDATE`? Where's the data supposed to come from?

Comment: Assign a default value if the data have to be the same for all rows. Otherwise write an insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Use `returning`.

```
create table t(id serial, a int, b int);
insert into t(a,b) (1,2) returning id;
```